# How can I index this numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

Given a numpy matrix `a` of shape `(5,3)`, and a index vector `b` of shape `(5,)`, where each entry in the index vector is between 0 to 2, how can I create a new vector `c` based on `a` and its index vector `b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `arange` for the other dimension:

```
c = a[np.arange(5), b]
```